# On Touchable highlights add componant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to add exported component on `TouchableHighlight` in react-native.

```
var MessageBox = require('./GiftedMessengerContainer');

var MyAppName = React.createClass({

 _openGiftedMessanger(){
   return (<MessageBox  style={styles.container}/>);
  },

    render: function() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.imButton}
                onPress={this._openGiftedMessanger}>
                <Text>Open Chat Room</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          }
          </View>
        );
    }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAppName', () => AppName);
```

And my module is,

```
import React, {
  Linking,
  Platform,
  ActionSheetIOS,
  Dimensions,
  View,
  Text,
  //Navigator,
  Component,
} from 'react-native';

var GiftedMessenger = require('react-native-gifted-messenger');
var Communications = require('react-native-communications');


// var STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Navigator.NavigationBar.Styles.General.StatusBarHeight;
// if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
//   var ExtraDimensions = require('react-native-extra-dimensions-android');
//   var STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = ExtraDimensions.get('STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT');
// }


class GiftedMessengerContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._isMounted = false;
    this._messages = this.getInitialMessages();

    this.state = {
      messages: this._messages,
      isLoadingEarlierMessages: false,
      typingMessage: '',
      allLoaded: false,
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;    

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        typingMessage: 'React-Bot is typing a message...',
      });
    }, 1000); // simulating network

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        typingMessage: '',
      });
    }, 3000); // simulating network


    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleReceive({
        text: 'Hello Awesome Developer', 
        name: 'React-Bot', 
        image: {uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}, 
        position: 'left', 
        date: new Date(),
        uniqueId: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000), // simulating server-side unique id generation
      });
    }, 3300); // simulating network
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  getInitialMessages() {
    return [
      {
        text: 'Are you building a chat app?', 
        name: 'React-Bot', 
        image: {uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}, 
        position: 'left', 
        date: new Date(2016, 3, 14, 13, 0),
        uniqueId: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000), // simulating server-side unique id generation
      },
      {
        text: "Yes, and I use Gifted Messenger!", 
        name: 'Awesome Developer', 
        image: null, 
        position: 'right', 
        date: new Date(2016, 3, 14, 13, 1),
        uniqueId: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000), // simulating server-side unique id generation
      },
    ];
  }

  setMessageStatus(uniqueId, status) {
    let messages = [];
    let found = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < this._messages.length; i++) {
      if (this._messages[i].uniqueId === uniqueId) {
        let clone = Object.assign({}, this._messages[i]);
        clone.status = status;
        messages.push(clone);
        found = true;
      } else {
        messages.push(this._messages[i]);
      }
    }

    if (found === true) {
      this.setMessages(messages);
    }
  }

  setMessages(messages) {
    this._messages = messages;

    // append the message
    this.setState({
      messages: messages,
    });
  }

  handleSend(message = {}) {

    // Your logic here
    // Send message.text to your server

    message.uniqueId = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000); // simulating server-side unique id generation
    this.setMessages(this._messages.concat(message));

    // mark the sent message as Seen
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setMessageStatus(message.uniqueId, 'Seen'); // here you can replace 'Seen' by any string you want
    }, 1000);

    // if you couldn't send the message to your server :
    // this.setMessageStatus(message.uniqueId, 'ErrorButton');
  }

  onLoadEarlierMessages() {

    // display a loader until you retrieve the messages from your server
    this.setState({
      isLoadingEarlierMessages: true,
    });

    // Your logic here
    // Eg: Retrieve old messages from your server

    // IMPORTANT
    // Oldest messages have to be at the begining of the array
    var earlierMessages = [
      {
        text: 'React Native enables you to build world-class application experiences on native platforms using a consistent developer experience based on JavaScript and React. https://github.com/facebook/react-native', 
        name: 'React-Bot', 
        image: {uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}, 
        position: 'left', 
        date: new Date(2016, 0, 1, 20, 0),
        uniqueId: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000), // simulating server-side unique id generation
      }, {
        text: 'This is a touchable phone number 0606060606 parsed by taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text', 
        name: 'Awesome Developer', 
        image: null, 
        position: 'right', 
        date: new Date(2016, 0, 2, 12, 0),
        uniqueId: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000), // simulating server-side unique id generation
      },
    ];

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setMessages(earlierMessages.concat(this._messages)); // prepend the earlier messages to your list
      this.setState({
        isLoadingEarlierMessages: false, // hide the loader
        allLoaded: true, // hide the `Load earlier messages` button
      });
    }, 1000); // simulating network

  }

  handleReceive(message = {}) {
    // make sure that your message contains :
    // text, name, image, position: 'left', date, uniqueId
    this.setMessages(this._messages.concat(message));
  }

  onErrorButtonPress(message = {}) {
    // Your logic here
    // re-send the failed message

    // remove the status
    this.setMessageStatus(message.uniqueId, '');
  }

  // will be triggered when the Image of a row is touched
  onImagePress(message = {}) {
    // Your logic here
    // Eg: Navigate to the user profile
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GiftedMessenger
        ref={(c) => this._GiftedMessenger = c}

        styles={{
          bubbleRight: {
            marginLeft: 70,
            backgroundColor: '#007aff',
          },
        }}

        autoFocus={false}
        messages={this.state.messages}
        handleSend={this.handleSend.bind(this)}
        onErrorButtonPress={this.onErrorButtonPress.bind(this)}
        maxHeight={Dimensions.get('window').height} //- Navigator.NavigationBar.Styles.General.NavBarHeight - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT}

        loadEarlierMessagesButton={!this.state.allLoaded}
        onLoadEarlierMessages={this.onLoadEarlierMessages.bind(this)}

        senderName='Awesome Developer'
        senderImage={null}
        onImagePress={this.onImagePress}
        displayNames={true}

        parseText={true} // enable handlePhonePress, handleUrlPress and handleEmailPress
        handlePhonePress={this.handlePhonePress}
        handleUrlPress={this.handleUrlPress}
        handleEmailPress={this.handleEmailPress}

        isLoadingEarlierMessages={this.state.isLoadingEarlierMessages}

        typingMessage={this.state.typingMessage}
      />
    );
  }

  handleUrlPress(url) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
  }

  // TODO
  // make this compatible with Android
  handlePhonePress(phone) {
    if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
      var BUTTONS = [
        'Text message',
        'Call',
        'Cancel',
      ];
      var CANCEL_INDEX = 2;

      ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions({
        options: BUTTONS,
        cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX
      },
      (buttonIndex) => {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
          case 0:
            Communications.phonecall(phone, true);
            break;
          case 1:
            Communications.text(phone);
            break;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  handleEmailPress(email) {
    Communications.email(email, null, null, null, null);
  }

}


module.exports = GiftedMessengerContainer;
```

How to add custom views on my screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of something  called as states (in React terms). When onPress function is invoked you set a state variable to open/close which then can be used to show/hide the custom view. For ex:

```
var MessageBox = require('./GiftedMessengerContainer');

var MyAppName = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
         messageBoxShow: 'false'
     }
  },

 _openGiftedMessanger:function(){
   this.setState({
      messageBoxShow: 'true'
   });
  },

    render: function() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.imButton}
                onPress={this._openGiftedMessanger}>
                <Text>Open Chat Room</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          {this.state.messageBoxShow === 'true' ? <MessageBox  style={styles.container}/> : null };
          </View>
        );
    }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAppName', () => AppName);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.It really helpful and working fine here. But the thing is why we need to add MessageBox on initial load of application? Why we not add on button click instead of show and hide. Is it better practice if in my application having more than  25-50 views?

Comment: MessageBox is indeed only added when you click the button. It is just the way it is done in react. As you might know, react application is hierarchy of components and everytime any state change happens the whole hierarchy is updated. Every component has a render function and in the render function we choose what needs to be rendered for that component based on state. In this case, the state is affected by the button. I would suggest you look up videos about working of react. Hope it helps. Let me know if it is not clear still.

Comment: do you have idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140648/unexpected-token-module-build-failed-syntaxerror ?